# Role based relations

Tags: laravel

I have a project where different user types exist , each of them should have relations with specific models in the system .

for example , the Customer has Purchases , while the Seller has Items , the Seller actually can be a buyer in some cases , but he should still have his own access to Items as well .

I'm not sure that I explained the problem in a good way but what I imagine for the solution to be like this

Assuming that we use laratrust or any package that provides roles and permissions traits to a model , which happens to be the User model , representing all user types in the system .

the code will be like this ...

```
public function items(){
   if($this->hasRole("Seller"))
      return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
   }
}
```

the problem with the morphic relation approach - in my point of view - is that there will be another layer between the loggedIn user and the access type , which is not easing the solution at all , so I must type something like this

```
$user->type->items;
```

the code above is to obtain items set by the Seller , not mentioning that the type will be ambiguous along the whole application , and I dont imagine that we will get red of laratrust as role management authority .

also the multi-guard approach is risky , because the user models actually are not separated as I mentioned above , rather , they have strict relations with other models and must be well specified , another problem that I must deal with upgrading / downgrading privileges of some user , which I think is hard to do with multi-guard approach .

the question is , how to define a conditional relation , that relates the user with some models based on his role ?

Comment: Seems overly complicated for not much benefit. By definition, relationships can be nullable or empty, and if you don't access the relationship, it won't be used. In your code, conditionally load and use the relationship based on the role. The definition can always be there, and even if it is loaded accidentally for an incorrect role, it'll likely be null or empty anyway, so no harm done.

Comment: so how do I simply return null if the role is not allowed ? , the function must return a relationship instance ...